# Creating a mask out of numbers

Tags: images

I need to create a hallow number, create a red outline, and fill it in with a specific design.  Is there a way I can create an outline of a number 2 and fill it with the design?  And also, If parts of the design bleed over the boundaries of the number 2 it gets clipped?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator CS5

Answer (score 0):

The first part is Easy, in Illustrator (cs3,cs4,cs5) just download the number in vector, EPS or AI format, ten create an outline, hit Expand button, get rid of the fill, and in another layer (under) just put the design you want.

--bobby, yoshi's man for graphics, testing superuser :)

if you have to create the number is easier, just create it, (yes, via Shapes, with the "Pen Tool" fill it with any color, then...

N.1 Make an outline with other color, (on the top right side where the color is you can see a square and a frame, the square is for fill, and the frame is obviously for the frame, put different colors so it will be easier to recognize.

N.2 Go to the Stroke button (Windows > Stoke) and put the number of the size for the outline 5,10,15, etc.

N.3 make it an "objects" with the command Ctr+Shift+O or go to (Object > Expand)

*REMEMBER you have to have the number 2 selected*

And then hit the letter "A" on your keyboard, and the arrow will turn white, this allows you to move independent the fill and the outlines, so select the fill and hit (Ctrl+X) or just copy it and then delete it, but paste it in another layer on the top, this fill part is for the clipping mask.

N.6 Create a new layer under the layer of the number "2 Outlines" layer, and put your design there.

If your design is bigger that the number, you will have to do a clipping mask on it, so *lock your Number "2 Outlines" layer, then select everything with your number "2 fill" layer on the top, and go to (Object > Clipping Mask > Create)

but you have to lock the number "2 Outlines" layer so cannot be selected, just your design in the back, and the number "2 fill" layer on the front.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I have to create the number, do I do that by creating it via shapes?

Comment: How do I create the outline or get rid of the fill?